# Can we create deadlock without thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can we create deadlock without thread in java? This question was asked in java interview can anybody answer this.

Comment: You can't do anything without a thread in Java.  Running `java` creates a thread.  The "main" thread.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to run code without at least one thread. A single thread can block itself in some cases eg attempting to upgrade a read lock to a write lock.

When a thread resource starves itself, it is called a [livelock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock)

I added more detail on livelocks in Java here [Is it possible for a thread to Deadlock itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493441/is-it-possible-for-a-thread-to-deadlock-itself/53150529#53150529)

It is also possible to create a deadlock without creating an additional thread e.g. the finalizer thread and the main thread could deadlock each other.